# What does the M-expression list[x;y] do in LISP?

Tags: lisp, s-expression

I was reading [this](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/recursive.html) paper on LISP by McCarthy (way above my skill set). While defining the evaluation of (LABEL, f, e) [here](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive/node3.html), he used an M-expression (I think it's an M-expression, correct me if I am wrong)  `list[x;y]`.
{Actually, `list[cadar[e];car[e]]`}.

According to how I understood it, it symbolizes (e1, e2) where e1 and e2 are S-expressions. Did I get it right or is it something else, and what is the corresponding expression for `list[x;y]`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the metalanguage, the expression `list[a; b]` denotes the application of the function `list` to two arguments, which builds a list with two elements, which are the result of the evaluation of `a` and `b` respectively.

In the language of the S-expressions, so, this would be written as the usual function call: `(LIST a b)`, that is a list with the first element the name of the function (`LIST`) and the rest of the elements the actual parameters of the function. Note that here I use the notation `(a b)` for S-expressions, and not `(a, b)`. McCarthy itself changed this notation later, and in the `LISP 1.5 Programmer’s Manual. 2. ed. Cambridge, Mass: MIT Pr, 1979.` the new notation is used.

Comment: What would be then the difference between `cons[x ; y]` and `list[x ; y]` then?
Is it that in `list[x ; y]` , `x` and `y` stand for atoms?

Comment: @Geek, `x` and `y` stands for generic (meta-)expressions which evaluates to data (for instance atoms, conses, numbers, etc., in other words, S-expressions). `List` differs from `cons` since a cons is a pair of two S-expressions, while a list of 1 element is a cons of the element with NIL, a list of 2 elements is a cons of the first element with the cons of the second with NIL, etc. See pages 36-37 of [Lisp 1.5 Programming Manual](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf), in which the first part is a rewriting of the article that you cited.

Comment: @Geek `(cons x y)` constructs a cell whose `car` is the value of `x` and whose `cdr` is the value of `y`. For instance `(cons 1 2)` makes `(1 . 2)`. By contrast, `(list 1 2)` makes `(1 2)`, an object which contains two cons cells, equivalent to `(1 . (2 . nil))`.  The expression `(list x y)` produces the same result as `(cons x (cons y nil))`. The `list` function has to iterate over the arguments and allocate cells to them (perhaps by calling `cons`, one time for each argument), putting those together into a `nil`-terminated list which is returned.